# Help writing a follow-up letter asking a professor to act as an academic reference

Tags: recommendation-letter, email

I need your help on how to write a follow-up letter requesting a professor to act as an academic reference.

I wrote to the professor a couple of weeks ago but so far I have not had any response. The original e-mail explained how we met (I was a visiting student at her lab), how long ago that was, what I´ve been doing since then and why it is important for me to have her recommendation. I know she travels a lot but she always uses an out-of-office auto-reply, which I didn´t get this time, so I don´t know whether she even got the e-mail or not. Should I write a brief note indicating that I sent her an e-mail a few weeks back and then include the content of the original e-mail? (I am writing from another e-mail address in case the first one was blocked by the spam filter). Or should I merge the brief note and the original content in a new e-mail? Any help will be greatly appreciated!